# Calculate dual graph of planar Graphics map

Tags: graphs-and-networks, image-processing

This diagram from a Wikipedia article illustrates what I hope to accomplish in Mathematica:

> [image]

I have a planar map in `Graphics` format. Here are two very simple examples with the same dual:

```
map1 = Graphics[{
    Orange, Rectangle[{0, 0}],
    Blue,   Rectangle[{1, 0}],
    Red,    Rectangle[{2, 0}]
}];
map2 = Graphics[{
    Orange, Disk[{0, 0}, 3],
    Blue,   Disk[{0, 0}, 2],
    Red,    Disk[{0, 0}, 1]
}];
Column[{map1, map2}]
```

[image]

I would like to write a function `dual` to find the dual graph of such a map. For example:

```
dual[map1]

(* Graph[{Orange -> Blue, Blue -> Red}] *)

dual[map2]

(* Graph[{Orange -> Blue, Blue -> Red}] *)
```

I might look into purchasing a copy of *Mathematica in Action* since I’ve heard that Chapter 17 contains some relevant code for finding the dual in the supplemental `MapColoring` package. It looks like the book uses the older (pre-version 8) Combinatorica graphs. Still, I’m not sure how to transform the map from `Graphics` into a better format.

Answer (score 8):

Note: The following needs a properly color quantized image as input. Color quantization for general images is a problem on its own that depends on many factors and is not addressed below.

First we will go step by step, then wrapping up all of it in a function:

Import some discrete-colored image:

```
ii = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vdgV.png"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then we find the list of colors in that image:

```
ru = Union@Flatten[ImageData@ii, 1]
(* {{1., 0., 0., 1.}, {1., 0.882353, 0., 1.}} *)
```

For each color we separate in different binary images

```
selCol[i_Image, col_] := ImageApply[1 - Unitize@Tr[# - col] &, i]
cols = selCol[ii, #] & /@ ru
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, for each of these images we separate the Morphological Components and we form a new array where each of them is represented by a different number. Perhaps there is an easier way, but the following works:

```
cs = Fold[#1 + Unitize@#2 Max@#1 + #2 &,  MorphologicalComponents/@ cols];
Colorize@cs
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For each component we need its neighbors to build up the edges:

```
nei = ComponentMeasurements[cs, "Neighbors"]
(* {1 -> {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}, 2 -> {1}, 4 -> {1}, 6 -> {1}, 8 -> {1}, 10 -> {1}} *)
```

And so we build our edges:

```
edges = DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Union @@ Thread /@ nei]
(* {1 -> 2, 1 -> 4, 1 -> 6, 1 -> 8, 1 -> 10} *)
```

Finally, for coloring the vertex we want to recover which color in the original image correspond to each vertex number:

```
ucs = Union@Flatten@cs;
colCorr = Extract[ImageData[ii], #] & /@ Position[cs, #, 2, 1] & /@ ucs
(* {{{1., 0., 0., 1.}}, {{1., 0.882353, 0., 1.}}, {{1., 0.882353, 0., 1.}}, 
    {{1., 0.882353, 0., 1.}}, {{1., 0.882353, 0., 1.}}, {{1., 0.882353, 0., 1.}}} 
*)
```

we now build the vertex coloring rules:

```
vStyle = Thread[ Rule[ucs, RGBColor @@@ Flatten[colCorr, 1]]]
(*
{1 -> RGBColor[1., 0., 0., 1.], 
 2 -> RGBColor[1., 0.882353, 0., 1.], 
 4 -> RGBColor[1., 0.882353, 0., 1.], 
 6 -> RGBColor[1., 0.882353, 0., 1.], 
 8 -> RGBColor[1., 0.882353, 0., 1.], 
 10 -> RGBColor[1., 0.882353, 0., 1.]}
 *)
```

And finally the Graph:

```
Graph[edges, VertexSize -> 0.2, VertexStyle -> vStyle, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

So now we will pack it into one function:

```
mkDual[ii_Image, OptionsPattern[{CornerNeighbors -> False}]] :=
 Module[{selCol, ru, cols, cs, nei, edges, ucs, colCorr, vStyle},
  selCol[i_Image, col_] := ImageApply[1 - Unitize@Tr[# - col] &, i];
  ru = Union@Flatten[ImageData@ii, 1];
  cols = selCol[ii, #] & /@ ru;
  cs = Fold[#1 + Unitize@#2 Max@#1 + #2 &,  MorphologicalComponents[#, 
                    CornerNeighbors -> OptionValue[CornerNeighbors]] & /@ cols];
  nei = ComponentMeasurements[cs, "Neighbors"];
  edges = DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Union @@ Thread /@ nei];
  ucs = Union@Flatten@cs;
  colCorr = Extract[ImageData[ii], #] & /@ Position[cs, #, 2, 1] & /@ ucs;
  vStyle = Thread[Rule[ucs, RGBColor @@@ Flatten[colCorr, 1]]];
  Graph[edges, VertexSize -> 0.2, VertexStyle -> vStyle, VertexLabels -> "Name"]]
```

and use it on color-quantized images of some country flags

```
riq = Import /@ 
       {"https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqpFO.png","https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQwSA.png", 
        "https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyIt7.png","https://i.stack.imgur.com/g334k.png",
        "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-vRxXWRa_4zk/UXz62fD9wRI/AAAAAAAAAs8/9bFvYHh8ozg/s1600/Antwerp+Flag.png"};
GraphicsGrid@Partition[Flatten[{#, mkDual[#, CornerNeighbors -> True]} & /@ riq[[1 ;; 4]]],  2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
{#, mkDual[#, CornerNeighbors -> False]} &@riq[[5]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How do I determine the second argument to `MorphologicalPerimeter`? The `.25` value doesn’t work automatically for most maps I try, like these: `CountryData[#, "Flag"] /@ {"Burma", "Canada", "China", "Jamaica", "Malaysia"}`

Comment: @hftf What would be the desired result for (for example) `"Canada"`?

Comment: `{Red -> White, Red -> White, Red -> White}`.

Comment: @hftf Nah, that images may  **seem** to have "plain" colors, but they haven't ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sISrQ.png)

Comment: I'm using the latest Mathematica. I believe the country flags now use vector Graphics.

Comment: @hftf Try `Graph[{Red -> White, Red -> White, Red -> White}]`. I believe you're not using the standard Mathematica concepts for Vertex names

Comment: Sorry; I was using `{Red -> White, ...}` as just an informal description of the wanted end result. Suppose 1 represents the white region and 2, 3, 4 represent the three red regions for `"Canada"`. Then the graph should be like `{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4}`.

Comment: @hftf Doesn't work on V9

Comment: What about `DominantColors[CountryData["Germany", "Flag"]]` → `{RGBColor[1., 0.807, 0.], RGBColor[0., 0., 0.], RGBColor[0.866, 0., 0.]}`?

Comment: You removed the [tag:graphics] tag, but half of my question was about Graphics. Your answer relies on applying `MorphologicalComponents` to a bitmap converted from a `Graphics`. While that could be a usable solution in many cases, I don't think it will work (efficiently or not) for all vector `Graphics`, especially ones with a lot of detail. It might be a convoluted example, but try it on `Image[CountryData["BritishVirginIslands", "Flag"]]`.

Comment: Another flag that doesn't work as expected is `Image[CountryData["Panama","Flag"]]`, since there should be three White–Blue and three White–Red edges, and no Red–Blue ones.

Comment: +1 beautiful answer! Should this work fast with any size image? I tried [with THIS](http://starfishquay.blogspot.com/2013/04/vexillology-or-fun-with-flags-antwerp.html) but it failed.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Thanks :). The problem is threefold: the color quantization scheme, the dithering  and the corner neighbor spec for `MorphologicalComponents`. The first two are quite tricky to address for a "general" image. I added a corner neighbor option to be able to process your image, but please note that I used the 600x400 version of it because it's the only one "properly" quantized.

Comment: It should be clarified that your function requires a color quantized bitmap. Even though in v10 the country flags are color quantized vector graphics, just using Rasterize won't quantize them properly.

Comment: @hftf Please re-read the first few paragraphs again :D

Comment: I did. The point I am trying to make is that I already have a "properly color quantized" _vector_ image. The original question asks for a function like `quantized vector → dual graph` but the answer gives a function like `quantized bitmap → dual graph` while saying that a function like `quantized vector → quantized bitmap` is out of scope…

Comment: While most flags are simple enough to be represented as a medium-sized bitmap image, I cannot be confident that this answer will work on any Graphics in general. Since the `quantized vector → quantized bitmap` step can only lose information, I am hoping there's another method that can calculate the graph (from intersections, unions, etc.) using vector Graphics shapes.